# Reading stata files with large variables in stata and R

Tags: r, memory, stata

I am trying to read the `stata` files of size 320 MB in `stata` and `R` with more than 5000 variables. I used first `stata` to read the file but the maximum variable that it can read is 5000. So, I can't use stata to read the `stata` file. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to read the `stata` file using `stata` by first asking to keep only variables (I know the variables) so that number of variables is less than 5000?
2. Is there way that I can read this `stata` file in `R`?. I am using 32 bit (Vista) and `R` is giving me the error. `"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 21k.Kb"`.

I used the following R code to read the file :

```
  #The stata file is in the webpage: http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/scf/scf_2010survey.htm#STATADAT
#1. set mem 400m
set maxvar 4000
use p10i6.dta, clear
keep x8166 x8167 x8168 x8163 x8164 x2422 x2506 x2606 x2623 x604 x614 x623 x716 x507  x513 x526 x1706 x1705 x1806 x1805 x1906 x1905 x2002 x2012 x1409 x1509 x1609 x1415 x1515 x1615 x1417 x1517 x1617 x1619 x1621 x3124 x3224 x3324 x3129 x3229 x3329 x3335 x3408 x3412 x3416 x3420 x3424 x3428 x4020 x4024 x4028 x4018 x4022 x4026 x4030 x4022 x4026 x4030 x4018 x3507 x3511 x3515 x3519 x3523 x3527 x3506 x3510 x3514 x3518 x3522 x3526 x3529 x3804 x3807 x3810 x3813 x3816 x3818 x3930 x3721 x3821 x3823 x3825 x3827 x3829 x3822 x3824 x3826 x3828 x3830 
save p10i6.dta, clear     


#2. 
        library (foreign)
        year<-2010
        yr <- substr( year , 3 , 4 )
        p10i6.dta<-read.dta(paste0( "p" , yr , "i6.dta" ))
        saveRDS(p10i6.dta,file=paste0( "p" , yr , "i6.rda" ))
        p10i6.rda<-readRDS(paste0( "p" , yr , "i6.rda" ))
```

Comment: Please provide us with a reproducible example, data and code to read the file.

Comment: you can use the skip option.  http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/infile-dictionary-options/

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: I have updated the question with the codes.

Comment: Try `use x8166 x8167 ... using p10i6, clear` then `save new_file`.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico: infile is for ASCII. I need help for stata file.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: Thanks but I got an error:`variable x8166 not found
r(111)`. Note that there is a variable x8166,however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you have a StataIC or an older version of Stata. The current Stata/SE and Stata/MP can read up to more than 32.000 variables. So the first logical step would be to upgrade your Stata to a version that can handle larger datasets. If the problem doesn't originate from a lack of available memory, that is... For that, the error message of Stata would be helpful.

As Richard Herron told already in the comments, you should be able to read in a subset of the data using:

```
use X8166 X8167 ... using p10i6, clear
```

remember that Stata is case sensitive. The variables are called `X...` instead of `x...`, according to the website you linked to.

If you want to load the data into R using the `foreign` package, make sure you set the memory available to R to the maximum possible on R. On Vista that's going to be about 3.5Gb:

```
memory.limit(3500)
```

If that doesn't help, your dataset is going to be too big, and you can use any of the ASCII methods from either Stata or R to load the ASCII data provided at the website.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I didn't realize the x's were cap. My RAM is 2GB. I guess I need to move to 64 bits to use `R`.

Comment: I guess you need to move to a new computer especially. For decent work with big datasets, you need indeed a 64bit system and at least 6Gb of RAM. I currently work with 8Gb, and that's still limiting me on some datasets. Depends on how often you need it ofcourse, but as Uwe Liggies said: thinking hurts and RAM is cheap.

Comment: Be careful with loading large stuff in R, it's easy to get the software to max out disk space. I find loading large datasets easier and safer in Stata. R can do it well with SQL, though.

Answer (score 4):

To read the data into R, there might be a way to do this with the `memisc` package `Stata.file` function. Instead of reading in all the variables, select the variables that you need using subset. For example:

```
require(memisc)

?Stata.file
d1 <- subset(
        Stata.file(paste0( "p" , yr , "i6.dta" )),
        select=c(x8166, x2606, x2623, x604)
    )
```